# Obscured and Unobscured event. Error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I try to write an Obscured and Unobscured event, but there is one Error in:

```
PhoneApplicationFrame phoneAppRootFrame = (Application.Current as App).RootFrame
```

error:

```
Auf den Member 'Timer.App.RootFrame.get' kann nicht mit einem Instanzenverweis zugegriffen werden. Qualifizieren Sie ihn stattdessen mit einem Typnamen.
```

The Error is in German, because I'm using the German Version of Visual Studio

How I can solve the problem?

EDIT:

code:

```
PhoneApplicationFrame phoneAppRootFrame = (Application.Current as App).RootFrame;
phoneAppRootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
phoneAppRootFrame.Unobscured += Unobscured;
```

Comment: Please provide an english version of the error to make things easier. I used google translate and got "This member 'Timer.App.RootFrame.get' can not be accessed with an instance reference. Qualify him instead with a type name." This doesn't coincide with the posted code. Can you provide a bit more of the surrounding code?

Comment: ok, i have post more code (look at EDIT:)

Comment: Try `PhoneApplicationFrame phoneAppRootFrame = (Application.Current as App)::RootFrame;`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but when I try this, there are two errors 1. Syntaxfehler. "." erwartet.     2.The same error as before

Comment: Where are you making these changes? In App.xaml.cs? If that's the case you should just be saying `RootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;` etc. If it's in another class, I'm not sure why it's failing with your initial method. Are you sure the error is actually on the line you think it is?

Comment: I have tried this in MainPage.xaml.cs. Sorry, I have forgot to post a link: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_handle_phone_calls_and_other_interruptions_in_Windows_Phone